# write() in sys/uio.h returns -1

Tags: c++, g++, ubuntu-9.10, ftp-client, x86-64

I'm using
Ubuntu Server 9.10
AMD Phenom 2 cpu
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9) 4.4.1

trying to run the application pftp-shit v 1.11, which runs successfully until the remote file list is going to be saved (into .pftp//pftpfxp--).

The following code in tcp.cc is executed successfully:

```
int outfile_fd = open(name, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR | O_BINARY)
```

which returns a file descriptor int (in my case 6) - name is a char array containing a valid path to my file which successfully i created.
and successfully running:

```
fchmod(outfile_fd, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

and

```
access(name, W_OK)
```

The issue occurs during running the function (from sys/uio.h)

```
write(outfile_fd, this->control_buffer, read_length)
```

which returns -1. -1 is of returned if nothing was written and otherwise a non-negative integer is returned which is equal to the number of bytes written.

Anyone having a clue how I can get the write function to work?

Comment: posting some source code with comments would make it easier for the readers to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

> On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

Perhaps `errno` could give you some hints about what's wrong.

```
write(outfile_fd, this->control_buffer, read_length);
```

Does `read_length` contain correct number of bytes to be written?

Answer (score 0):

Are the directory and file definitely writable by the user attempting the write? Maybe try running it in /tmp just as a test.